# Using DataBinder.Eval() in style attribute of an asp.net control

Tags: asp.net, css, repeater, databinder

I've a asp.net linkbutton inside asp.net repeater control which renders multiple link buttons. I want to set the style of each and every linkbutton dynamically.

I'm trying

```
style="color:#6D7B8D;font-size:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%>;"
```

But i'm getting "The server tag is not well formed" error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My understanding is that using server tags for attributes requires that the server tag be used for the **entire** attribute value.  Try changing it to this:

```
style='<%# "color:#6D7B8D;font-size:" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") + ";" %>'
```

Notice how the entire style attribute is being constructed in C# code between the server tags.

Comment: In my point of view the apostrophes are unnecessary: just type style=<%# "color:#6D7B8D;font-size:" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") + ";" %>

Answer (score 4):

Write it like that:

```
style='color:#6D7B8D;font-size:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%>;'
```

With single quotes instead of double quotes around the style

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<%# Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>
```

To:

```
Text='<%# Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use trenary operator within it-- to custom the font size

```
style='<%# "color:#6D7B8D;font-size:"Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fontSize"))<5?"40":"30");" %>'
```