# The server tag is not well formed.(databinder.eval)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to working the following code.

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="Grid" runat="server"  DataKeyField="KeyID" CssClass="grid"
...
<asp:CheckBox runat="server"  ID="checkBox-<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"KeyID")%>" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:CheckBox>
```

When I run the code,I have got the below error:

```
Error   25  The server tag is not well formed.
```

Note : This is working without runat="server".
What is the remedy for this problem ?

Comment: try single quotes instead of double outside the Databinder.Eval..  e.g.  ID='checkBox-<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"KeyID")%>'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using DataBinder.Eval() in style attribute of an asp.net control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434744/using-databinder-eval-in-style-attribute-of-an-asp-net-control)   (key point: you can't use `DataBinder.Eval` for only part of an attribute value.)

Comment: @sylon it is didn't work to single qoutes too. ID='checkBox-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>'   Error 25 'checkBox-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Why do you need to set the ID of the checkbox? It will be set automatically when binding.

Comment: @KirkWoll I tried it. To different attribute is running.I think the problem is related to id.

Comment: I need to checkbox id for OnCheckedChanged event. So I will change background color of selected item in javascript.

Comment: @zeitgeist you don't need ID to do that... Also, OnCheckedChanged event is a postback event, not a javascript event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to set the ID of the CheckBox to do what you want to do (change the background color). Your CheckBox should look like this (I added the `KeyID` as the text value if you want to display it... or you can just remove that if you only want the checkbox):

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkbox" Text='<%# Eval("KeyID") %>' AutoPostBack="false"></asp:CheckBox>
```

Now your checkbox will render something like this:

```
<input id="MainContent_Grid_checkbox_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$Grid$ctl02$checkbox" /><label for="MainContent_Grid_checkbox_0">Value of KeyID</label>
```

Since all the names end with "checkbox", you can apply a function on the change event for those elements whose name ends with "checkbox". You didn't specify that this was a JavaScript question or if you are using jQuery... this answer uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<script>
    $('input[name$="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'white');
        }
    });
</script>
```

That will determine if the checkbox is checked, and if so it will set the background-color of its parent (the `<td>` that it is in, inside the DataGrid rendered HTML), depending on the value.

Likewise, you can go up to the next `parent()` and highlight the entire row.

Resources:
[jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

[OnCheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.oncheckedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -- an event that you would process in the code behind, not in JavaScript.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? You can just change it to: `$(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');` (extra parent() will get the parent of the `<td>`, which will be the `<tr>`). I can add javascript only option if you don't use jQuery.