# Error : The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

```
<asp:Image ID="imgteacher" runat="server" Height="150" Width="248" ImageUrl="ShowImage.ashx?id="+<%#Eval("CourseID") %>/>
```

Please, correct my writing mistake . I think my problem is because of only this row, therefore I only copied this row.

```
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using DataBinder.Eval() in style attribute of an asp.net control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434744/using-databinder-eval-in-style-attribute-of-an-asp-net-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error message is the data binding in the `ImageUrl` attribute. In order to make this work you need to exchange the double quotes by single ones and adjust the data binding code:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgteacher" runat="server" Height="150" Width="248" 
    ImageUrl='<%# "ShowImage.ashx?id="+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseID") %>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Simple wadata binding in the ImageUrl attribute

```
<asp:Image ID="imgteacher" runat="client" Height="150" Width="248" ImageUrl="ShowImage.ashx?id="+<%#Eval("CourseID") %>/>
```