# Change font color of row data in DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table in `SQL` with two columns

```
OrignalAmount  Currency     
5000          INR
2800          USD
5600          USD
5600          INR
```

And it is Bind Something like below

```
 OrignalAmount
    5000INR
    2800USD
    5600USD
    5600INR
```

I am able to bind these data into `DataGrid`. But i have condition is, if the `Currency` is INR then Amount data font is `RED` and if it is USD the color would be `Green`.
How do I get this please help.

Comment: Did you try doing it in the client side? I think it's easier, although you can do it on server side as well.

Comment: Does [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048762/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-condition-in-c-sharp) ? also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) check the last example.

Comment: Use Rowdatabound event to check currency of current row and apply styles accordingly or prepare styles while preparing data and boound to template accordingly. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434744/using-databinder-eval-in-style-attribute-of-an-asp-net-control

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change row color in datagridview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

Comment: refer the link http://www.dotnetwatch.com/change-the-specific-row--col389_ar.aspx

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I am not gonna change all the row. and inside data grid data is binding like 5000INR or 5600USD

Comment: So that is what provided in the duplicate marked question. you can just check if the cell value `Contains` `INR/USD` and then apply the condition.

Comment: @Gitz: Look at all the answers provided. You can find what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPay" Text='<%# Eval("message") %>' ForeColor='<%#Eval("Currency").ToString()=="USD"?System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#98b200"):System.Drawing.Color.Red%>' runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
protected void dgBoundItems(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            if (rv.Row.ItemArray[2].ToString() == "INR")
            {
                e.Item.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("class", "rupee");
            }
            else
            {
                e.Item.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("class", "dallar");
            }

        }

    }
```

use this style

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .rupee a:link {
            font-weight:normal;
            color:red;
        }

        .dallar a:link {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: or you can refer to this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15035/Change-datagrid-cell-properties